# Как получить перенаправленную ссылку

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

Необходимо получить ссылку сайта, на который можно попасть только с помощью перехода по другой ссылке

Пример: 
В браузере ввожу - example.com/post/random
И он переходит на - example.com/post/123456 (число каждый раз случайное) (эту ссылку мне и надо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://example.com/post/random')
print(response.geturl())
```

Видимо, сайт блокирует запросы не из браузера. Можете попробовать указать браузерный User Agent.

```
import urllib.request
req = urllib.request.Request(
    'http://example.com/post/random', 
    data=None, 
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36'
    }
)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
print(response.geturl())
```

Comment: Выпадает в ошибку urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Comment: @Fabriziog, дополнил

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее, всё работает

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить первую ссылку в цепочке перенаправлений:

```
>>> import requests  # $ pip install requests
>>> r = requests.head('http://httpbin.org/redirect/3')
>>> r.is_redirect
True
>>> r.next.url
'http://httpbin.org/relative-redirect/2'
```

Чтобы все перенаправления получить:

```
>>> pr = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/redirect/3')
>>> [r.url for r in pr.history]
['http://httpbin.org/redirect/3',
 'http://httpbin.org/relative-redirect/2', 
 'http://httpbin.org/relative-redirect/1']
```